# Use power button after lid is closed

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, acpi

Is there a way to still allow use of the power button after the laptop lid has been closed? I am using an old netbook as a server (OctoPrint for my 3D Printer) and keep it folded closed most of the time, but would like to be able to just push the power button to turn it on / off anyway. Is this even possible in Ubuntu or any version of linux, or is this impossible due to a limitation of the BIOS and how ACPI lid close communicates with the OS?

Comment: It is normally possible. Managing the lid close is dependent of the software you use (desktop environment, ubuntu version). Can you please add these information to your question?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.1